# Cyclic group collision resistant keyed cryptographic hash function

Tags: hash

I am self-studying cryptography from a book and have come across a really difficult question that's doing my head in.

I would be very grateful if somebody can help me out here with this difficult question. NOTE : This is not homework, as I am self-studying.

It would be great if someone can take the time to explain a solution for either a) or b) so I can begin to understand them better, thanks !

[image]

Comment: As for (b), well, suppose that $H_s$ wasn't collision resistant, that is, you had a black box that, given $h_2, ..., h_t$, could find a collision.  How could you use such a black box to solve the discrete log problem?  Actually, when you see a proof of "if problem A is hard, then problem B is hard", the proof is generally of the form "if you can solve problem B, then you can solve problem A".

Comment: Please post text rather than an image. An image is hard to read at the wrong resolution, impossible to read if you're blind, impossible to search, impossible to copy from… You can use [mathematical notations with MathJax's LaTeX-like syntax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).